# windows access violation and restarting kernel while using pyomo and a third-party app

Tags: pyomo

I run a script which calls in loops to Pyomo (to solve an optimization problem) and a third-party app as calculation engine (Power Factory). Then after a complete iteration an expected error pops-up that announces that there is a Windows access violation, then Kernel restarts. The attached picture describes in more detail the error message. There is a peculiarity since the same script perfectly works when I set different goal parameters. Thanks for your help in advance.

[image]